# Comparing multiple returns from method

Tags: java, path-finding, a-star

i have an array with multiple Nodes, these each have their H, G and F scores.

I get the H and G scores from a method called calculateGscore() and calculateHscore() which both return a double, the F score is H+G;

I have an ArrayList with open Nodes and i have to find the node with the lowest F score, but i dont know how to do this, the open arraylist can have 1 to 4 Nodes in it, no diaganol movement allowed.

What i have now is a for loop like:

```
 for(int i = 1; i < open.size(); i++){
            Gscore = open.get(i).getGscore(); // these methods are in the Node class.
            Hscore = open.get(i).getHscore();
            Fscore = Gscore + Hscore;

            if(Fscore < (calculateGscore(open.get(i-1)) + calculateHscore(open.get(i-1)))){          // these methods are in the pathFinder class.
                closed.add(open.get(i));
            }
            else{
                closed.add(open.get(i-1));
                open.remove(i-1);
            }
        }
```

but this doesnt work if there are 4 nodes in the open list, then it adds 2 nodes to the closed list instead of the only lowest.

I have this as an assignment so i cant change any code in the Node class, only in the pathfinder class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
double minFscore = open.get(0).getGscore() + open.get(0).getHscore();
Node minScoreNode = open.get(0);

for(int i = 1; i < open.size(); i++) {
    Gscore = open.get(i).getGscore(); // these methods are in the Node class.
    Hscore = open.get(i).getHscore();
    Fscore = Gscore + Hscore;

    if (Fscore < minFscore) {
         minScoreNode = open.get(i);
         minFscore = Fscore;
    }
}

open.remove(minScoreNode);
closed.add(minScoreNode);
```

This will loop through each node, find the node with the minimum fScore and will then move that node from the open list to the closed list. Your problem was that you were trying to add and remove before looking at the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a node **while** you are iterating your list. You have to iterate the **complete** list first; and while you are you doing that, you search for those that need to be deleted.

And then, when you processed **all** nodes; and you understand which one has that true "minimum" Fscore, then you delete **that** node.

Your code is trying to delete a node **before** you can possible know that its Fscore is smaller than those of **following** nodes!

You can do that by keeping track of the "current minimum fscore"; and the *index* of the node that has that "current minimum".

```
double currentMinimum = double max value (dont know the constant name right now)
int indexOfMinimum = 0;

for (int i=0; i < open.size(); i++) {
  if (fscore(open.get(i)) < currentMinimum) {
    currentMinimum = fscore(open.get(i));
    indexOfMinimum = i;
 }
}
```

and after loop, indexOfMinimum tells you which index to remove!

Comment: Yes i get that! I just cant seem to get how to do that in a for loop, i tried everything.

Comment: I put some example code into my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the track of lowestFScore node and keep comparing it with the current node's FScore in the iteration.

```
Node lowestFScoreNode = open.get(1);
for(int i = 1; i < open.size(); i++){
    Gscore = open.get(i).getGscore(); // these methods are in the Node class.
    Hscore = open.get(i).getHscore();
    Fscore = Gscore + Hscore;

    if(Fscore < (lowestFScoreNode.getGscore() + lowestFScoreNode.getHscore())) {
        lowestFScoreNode = open.get(i);
    }
}

return lowestFScoreNode;
```